# Модификатор Функция() : ????? { Тело }

Tags: c++

Увидел в книге пример кода на С++

```
public void Func(int x, int y):x(0),y(0) {}
```

Как это понимать? Куда копать?

Comment: Если пример действительно из книги, а не вырван из контекста, то объяснение должно быть рядом с примером. В той же книге.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В функцию передаются две переменные `x` и `y`, инициализируются на старте функции нулями.
Вообще такой синтаксис используется в конструкторе, инициализируются члены класса, (вызываются другие конструкторы), но не передаваемые параметры обнуляются. 
Код явно некорректный.

**UPD:** 
реальный пример такой инициализации:

```
HTTPRequest::HTTPRequest(QNetworkAccessManager & _networkManager, const QUrl & _url, const QString & _strCheckSum, const QString &  _strLicense)
: m_networkManager(_networkManager)
, m_url(_url)
, m_requestData(RSA_Mod_Public, sizeof(RSA_Mod_Public))
, m_pReply(NULL)
, m_strCheckSum(_strCheckSum)
, m_strLicense(_strLicense)
{
}
```

Здесь передаваемые в конструктор параметры инициализируют члены класса. А далее его наследник при инициализации вызывает конструктор родителя, передав ему свои параметры

```
InfoHttpRequest::InfoHttpRequest(QNetworkAccessManager & _networkManager, const QString &  _strLicense)
    : HTTPRequest(_networkManager, QUrl("http://dump.ru/"), "", _strLicense)
{
}
```

Comment: То есть это эквивалентно
Func(int x, int y) { x=0; y=0;}?

Comment: да   ......  ........

Comment: Смотрите апдейт ответа, этот код именно в таком виде не должен компилироваться, так как такая инициализация только в конструкторе проходит, а не в обычном методе.

Comment: Да, пересмотрел - действительно конструктор. И все же есть ли у этого какое-то название? Как это нагуглить?

Comment: Вот вам по теме пара ссылочек https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s16xw1a8.aspx   и https://habrahabr.ru/post/58818/

Comment: И пара реальных примеров в ответ )

Comment: _«Вообще такой синтаксис обычно используется в конструкторе»_ — этот синтаксис нигде кроме конструктора и не применим.

Comment: @ixSci мало ли, может давным давно и представленный автором книги вариант компилировался ) сейчас то конечно нет. Обычно тут и правдо лишнее слово.

Comment: @Mira, синтаксис из вопроса никогда не компилировался. Это какая-то смесь из C#/Java с конструктором из C++

Comment: Пример, предложенный ТСом с присваиванием, не является эквивалентным варианту со списком инициализации. Это будет сразу заметно, если x,y - константные или ссылочные члены класса. К тому же, запись `x=0` присваивает 0 аргументу функции, а не члену класса. Запись `x(0)` в инициализаторе конструктора присваивает `0` именно члену класса, а не аргументу функции.